# The simple function are dense in $L^{\infty} (X)$ if $\mu (X) \lt \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, show that:
>   The simple function are dense in $L^{\infty} (X)$ if $\mu (X) \lt \infty$

This is an exercise in Stein's functional analysis Page 35.
If $f \in L^\infty$ , then for any $e \gt0$ there exist $N$ , $f \lt Ne$ , a.e..
So use $E_n=\{x:-Ne +ne \le f \lt -Ne +(n+1)e \} $ and let $$f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{2N} (-Ne+ne)X_{E_n}(x)$$ where $X_{E_n}$ is the character function of $E_n$ , $0 \le n \le 2N$, then I can get $$\vert \vert f-f_n \vert \vert \lt e$$ 
Since I didn't use the assumption that $\mu (X) \lt \infty$ . Did I make something wrong in the proof ?

Comment: I don't have the book at hand to check for myself, but you might look closely at their definition of simple function. It may require that each set $E_n$ has finite measure.

Comment: Thank you ! I get the point now.

Comment: Nope. Generally it is not required for simple functions to have finite (in measure) support. However you proof is wrong. But just slightly. You have notation abuse. Your $f_{n}$ does not depend on $n$. It depends only $N$. So this proof can't be accepted as your choice of $N$ depends on fixed $e$. (However this is right way to think. Soon you'll get the proof. I think so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the simple functions *that are not necessarily supported on sets of finite measure* (simple functions are just measurable functions on $X$ with a finite image) are dense in $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ regardless of whether $\mu$ is finite. Note that you showed it for none negative bounded functions (I think), but it is easily extensible to complex functions in $L_{\infty}(\mu)$.